# Placing things in a users home directory with a .deb package

Tags: bash, shell-script, debian-installer

I am making a .deb installer and would like to place some files in the users home directory but I cannot hard code a username. Does any one know of any other places in the file system that I could put the files and folders or how to get it to put folders there? I do not want to use any postinst script to do this.

Comment: why down vote but leave no  reason y

Comment: Not me downvoting. Why don't you want to use the obvious `/var/tmp` or `/tmp`?

Comment: that does not help me much @MURU AS i do not wnat to use post inst

Comment: If a specific user is to receive a file, then hard coding that user name is probably logical. If all users to receive a file, then you can find them using `for user in /home/*` (although of course, it could be somewhere else than `/home` on your system). There is also the `getent passwd` command you can use to list all the users, but most are system users without a home directory.

Comment: "_the users home directory_" is that "the user's home directory" or "the users' home directory"? If it's the former how would you identify the specific user?

Answer (score 9):

You should never install files into home directories with packages.

Instead, you can install default configuration files to `/etc/skel` so that new users created after your package is installed will have these files copied to their newly created home directories. Users that already exist will not get these new files though. Your application can create config files in the user's home directory when it is run for the first time.

If you just want to add a file to everyone's (or a specific someone's) home directory then what you really want is a **configuration management system**. Installing a package is the wrong way to do this.

Comment: +10000 for “Don’t do that.” It's the only correct response.

Answer (score 0):

`~`, means the users folder which ever username the user has.

But I strongly reccomend that you use `/tmp` instead, there is no reason to use `~`.

Comment: Package installation is done as root, so the only value `~` will get is root's home directory, and that only in a maintainer script, which the OP says they don't want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Installing a deb package required to run under the root user.
Get the correct user who invoked sudo by using `SUDO_USER` (documented in [man sudo](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo))

Hence, to get the correct User Home Directory, use:

```
USER_HOME_DIR=$(getent passwd $SUDO_USER | cut -d: -f6)
echo "User Home Dir: $USER_HOME_DIR"
```

Test it from your Terminal:

```
sudo bash -c 'echo $(getent passwd $SUDO_USER | cut -d: -f6)'
```

Comment: There are other ways to be root aside from using `sudo`